# If array value begins with

Tags: php

I have an array of values.

My crawler scans the web page and inserts all the links, the links' titles and description is a multidimensional array.

But now I have a new array and I only want the links, descriptions and titles etc. if they begin with any value in the array ($bbc_values)

But  I don't really know how to do this. I have have gotten pretty far in terms of the actual code but can anyone give me any ideas a) why my code isn't working b) suggestions for my problem?

```
$bbc_values = array('http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/health-', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/politics-', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-',  'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/england-', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/northern_ireland-', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/scotland-', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/wales-', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/education-', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science_and_enviroment-', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment_and_arts-', 'http://edition.cnn.com/');


foreach ($links as $link) {
    $output = array(
        "title"       => Titles($link), //dont know what Titles is, variable or string?
        "description" => getMetas($link),
        "keywords" => getKeywords($link), 
        "link"        => $link                 
    );

    if (empty($output["description"])) {
        $output["description"] = getWord($link);
    }
}
$data = implode( " , ", $output['link']);
foreach ($output as $new_array) {
    if (in_array($output, $bbc_values)) {
    $news_stories[] = $new_array;
}

var_dump($news_stories);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I don't completely understand the code here. 
But I think $output array should be declared outside the first foreach loop and each array should be appended to it?
Because from the code you're writing, only the details of last $link will be stored inside the $output

Also, what is $data here? what are you using it for?

Comment: Please use "add comment" next time to discuss your doubts. Answers shall be only used to provide... well... answers.

Comment: he would not have the add comment option at his rep

Answer (score 0):

Turn `$bbc_values` into a regex:

```
$bbc_re = '/^('.implode('|', array_map('quotemeta', $bbc_values)).')/';
```

Then use this regex to filter the links.

```
foreach ($links as $link) {
  if (preg_match($bbc_re, $link)) {
    /* Do stuff with $link */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you what you want is to have an array with links that starts with of the links in the `bbc_values` and additionally a string `$data` with a comma separated list of all links. Try something this :

```
<?php

$bbc_values = array('http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/health-', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/politics-', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-',  'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/england-', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/northern_ireland-', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/scotland-', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/wales-', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/education-', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science_and_enviroment-', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment_and_arts-', 'http://edition.cnn.com/');

$news_stories = array();
$all_links = array();
$news_links = array();

foreach ($links as $link) {
    $item = array(
        "title"       => Titles($link), 
        "description" => getMetas($link),
        "keywords" => getKeywords($link), 
        "link"        => $link                 
    );

    if (empty($item["description"])) {
        $item["description"] = getWord($link);
    }


    foreach($bbc_values as $bbc_value) {
        // note the '===' . this is important
        if(strpos($item['link'], $bbc_value) === 0) {
            $news_stories []= $item;
            $news_links []=$item['link'];
            break;
        }
    }

    $all_links[] = $item['link'];
}

$data_all_links = implode(' , ', $all_links);
$data_news_links = implode(' , ', $news_links);
var_dump($news_stories);
```

Comment: He said he wants the links that _begin with_ elements of `$bbc_values`, not exact matches.

Comment: You fixed all the bugs in his code -- add my answer to it in the appropriate place and I think we'll have a complete solution.

Comment: sorry, when the script runs it just says: " array(0) {
}
  
"

Comment: can you post the contents of `$links`? Why there are '-' signs at the end of the bbc links?

Comment: I specifiy the url in $URL. I use simple_html_dom to generate links from a web page and then use functions to get their titles ad meta descriptions etc. $file  = file_get_html($URL); 
foreach ($file->find('a') as $theelement)  {     
    $abs_url = url_to_absolute($URL, $theelement->href);     
    if (!empty($abs_url)) {
         $links[] = $abs_url; 
    } 

  }

Comment: Why there are '-' signs at the end of the bbc links?

Comment: thats just how i have chosen to find the the urls.

Comment: This will break the search on the links as they not have this '-' signs in them (I expect)

Comment: because i only want bbc news stories and the (-) indicates a story is beginning

Comment: can you post a full example link that should match?

Comment: @hek2mgl how would i implode $news_stories as well.